# Rails Model find Where Not | Query where not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model with optional twitter integration.

I've added a 'username' attribute that is only filled when a user has completed twitter authentication.

I want to find all users with the integration. What is the best way to find all objects where an attribute is something, or where it is not nil?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Rails4 / Rails 5**:

`User.where.not(username: nil)`

**Rails 3:**

`User.where("username <> nil")`

I would love to see other responses

Comment: I am sorry, but you are not correct, at least as you phrased your question "where it is not empty". You need to use `User.where.not(username: '')` Why? Your query will only ignore non-nil (or NULL) values, *not* empty (aka blank) values. Subtle difference, but an important one. For example, if you have a text column and the user deletes all the text and saves. It is no longer `nil` (NULL), it is empty (as in empty string). Your query above will still include that record.

Comment: Thanks @Karl i updated the text in the question. field isn't updated by users, only by oauth integration and validation doesn't allow blank.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do just write the sql in the where statement:

```
User.where("username <> nil")
```

Comment: Blair Anderson's answer is definitely the better way of doing this. If you have a datastore that doesn't understand the `<>` operator, you'll get an error. `where.not` is datastore agnostic, translating to whatever it *does* understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute simple where not query like below

```
Modal.where.not(name: "abc")
```